# Adding colored corners to image

Tags: html, image, css

I need to add colored corners to an image (top-left in red, top-right in blue). The size of the corner is roughly 5 px.

Is it possible to do it with with styling only? Maybe coloring or adding an overlay image? It has to be on an element like this:

```
<img src="xxx.jpg" class="img_corners"></img>
```

CSS:

```
.img_corners
{
   /*styling for corners*/
}
```

Comment: This  will be tricky since `<img>` does not have `:before`/`:after` pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will need to wrap image inside a div as pseudo element are not supported for img

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border-style: solid;
}
div:before {
  border-width: 5px 0 0 5px;
  border-color: red;
  top: -4px;
  left: -4px;
}
div:after {
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-color: blue;
  top: -4px;
  right: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/any" />
</div>
```

**Edit**

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
}
div:before {
  border-width: 20px;
  border-width: 20px;
  border-color: red transparent transparent red;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
div:after {
  border-width: 20px;
  border-width: 20px;
  border-color: blue blue transparent transparent;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/any" />
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do triangle corners?

Comment: triangle corners means ? can you show a image ? @Alexey